# would this be a good design of a stack machine?

Tags: cpu

I've got an assignment to design a 8-bit stack machine I was wondering if this would work:
[image: 8bit Stack Machine Image]

My problem is this i'm not too sure if this design will work, i've hardly found any designs on a zero adress machine and the ones I have found have had a mar and correct me if i'm wrong the mar is an adress register, how can it count as a zero address machine that uses an address register? I may have gotten something wrong somewhere but I can't see it. Will this design work as i'm not using any memory?

Comment: I am sorry to inform you this site does better with specific technical discussion. Please come up with specific technical problems and we would be more then willing to help!.

Comment: @kortuk know where i can ask this question?

Comment: You might be able to slip by on stack overflow with this question as this is as much computer science as it is electrical engineering, but for the stack exchange sites this is not a great fit. You need to have a specific problem or technical item, a general, "Review my design and let me know anything you think is worth noting" is not a great fit. If you build it and have problems it would be a good time to come and ask questions. If you get stuck at a certain point of implementation, another great time to ask questions here.

Comment: @Kortuk - This is the second time a question is closed shortly after being asked, and while I'm writing an answer! :-(

Comment: @stevenvh, think about the question first. This question is open ended and could have 4 equally valid answers with no way to determine whom is right. It also asks for anything helpful to doing this. I know you have time to answer ever question, but why not some that are still on the unanswered tab!

Comment: stevenvh wouldnt mind hearing the answere >.>
@kirtuk i mightve not been good at really explaining my question, the reason why i was asking thsi is that ive had quite a few problems trying to find any zero address machines so i wasnt even sure if this design would work it was mostly quess work from bits and pieces ive read here and there, also ive had it closed on stack overflow aswell >.>

Comment: @user23012 Your question on stack overflow was closed by a mod. Usually if they know that the question can be answered on another site they will migrate the question to the proper location. The question as it is now is far to broad to be answered in its current form. That is why it was closed as "not constructive" instead of "off-topic". Give us more details as to what you are doing, whats not working, any testing you have done.

Comment: If you can turn it into a better question, flag for a mod and it can be reopened and then Steven can answer.

Comment: @kellenjb ok i'll try edit to try and explain my problem if its not enough i guess i'll just keep trying to search to get some of my confusion out of the way

Comment: Try OpenCores, there are several 8-bit CPUs there.

Comment: @Kortuk - This may come as a shock to you, but I *don't* know the answer to *every* question! ;-)

Comment: I only have a few shifts but this is still relatively open ended but has been refined a bit more. Just asking how to do any entire project does not really fit our style. This looks like it might be targeted down to a specific subset that someone can answer. As always if this draws only very poor answers that will signify if your edit was enough. Honestly though, with @stevenvh starting the answering you will normally get all good answers. I am willing to give the question a shot.

Comment: @user23012 i've edited the question so that it makes more sense. Feel free to change it back if i've changed the meaning at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read stevenvh correctly, his solution entails having an addressable data space, albeit one 'hidden' from the usual load/store kinds of access. From a hardware standpoint, a data address leaves the CPU, goes to an external RAM, and a data bus transfers data to/from the CPU, indistinguishable from a traditional load/store kind of CPU. But if your CPU only allows the kinds of access he mentions to that data space, then the programming model necessarily has to be stack-oriented and that would therefore be a legitimate implementation.

That said, an alternative implementation would be to actually implement the data space as a stack. The CPU interface to the stack unit could be an 8 bit bi-directional data bus, with two control lines, one to push the current data into the stack, one to read out (and remove) the topmost word of the stack. Now to make things convenient for working with your ALU, you *might* make it possible to read the top word without removing it, and you might also want to have direct access to the 2nd word. There are really several other ways you could go, too. You could directly wire the top stack word to the ALU A input and the 2nd stack word to the ALU B input; or you could put in a temporary data register to hold one input to the ALU while the other input comes from the stack. (This is where the mods are getting uptight about the open-endedness of your question, an I can see why - I don't want to design this for you, but hopefully this will give you a couple of ideas)

Lastly, let's put a little scope on this stack. As you said '8 bit', it should be pointed out that back in the day, the 6502 got by with a mere 256 bytes of stack. Certain HP calculators are stack oriented and get by with just *four* levels of stack. So as an academic exercise, as a proof-of-concept as it were, you needn't be concerned about supplying gobs and gobs of memory for your stack. I'm not sure there's actually a single-chip LIFO device that you could use - but if there is, and it's small, don't be put off. Actually making a hardware stack out of 74hc374s or something would probably be un-fun, but again, on the plus side, you could do a lot with just a few stack levels.

Comment: thanksboth yours and stevens answers have helped me somewhat understand things ive been reading, youve both been a big help sorry for not commenting earlier but i got an idea from these and was reading up on it and forgot to reply

Comment: The 6502 only had 256 bytes of stack when interfaced to machines with that much memory.  The popular Atari 2600 Video Computer System had a whopping 128 bytes of RAM, total, and applications typically only allotted 4-8 bytes for stack.

Answer (score 4):

*Note: this was the answer I wanted to post before you edited the question. I hope I interpreted the question rightly. The editing doesn't make it more clear to me, however.*

Do you want the stack in common RAM, or a (limited) separate stack?
If it's RAM-based you need an stack pointer pointing to the last used address or the next free address (both methods are used). Let's say you choose the first free address.
Pushing data on the stack is simply writing to the address pointed to, and decrementing the stack pointer. You can compare the new value with the lowest allowed address and generate a stack overflow interrupt if they're equal.
Popping data is the reverse: increment the stack pointer and read the data at that address. Again, you can compare the address with the highest allowed one, and generate a stack underflow interrupt if the stack pointer is higher. In that case you don't read the data as it will be invalid anyway.
Ideally the address range assigned to the stack would be managed by the OS, and be protected from direct access by applications. Most 8-bit microcontrollers, however, don't have hardware ring protection schemes and so the stack can't be hidden from view by applications.

If you have special stack registers instead of common RAM it's almost the same if you use a small RAM for it, it's just the stack overflow/underflow comparison values will be fixed.
An alternative way would be to use a series of D flip-flops which can be connected either up or down, depending on whether you push or pop. So depending on the direction FF 1 copies the data from FF 0, FF 2 copies from FF 1 etc., or FF 0 copies from FF 1, FF 1 copies from FF 2 etc. The complexity here is linear with the stack size, where it's fixed for the RAM approach.

Comment: thanks that's somewhat cleared somethings for me at least, i'll try and make the edit more clearer since  Kortuk thought it wasn't that good either

Comment: just to make sure Ive understood what you mean the stack in common with ram would be something like this http://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece5760/DE2/TinyCPU/Stack_machine_2010/ports/architecture.png  and the limited separate stack would look more like this http://www.pling.org.uk/cs/carimg/jorvik4.gif

Answer (score 2):

It's sometimes nice to have stack semantics that allow an arbitrary number of items to be pushed, provided that only the proper number are popped; the push-down stack illustrated provides such semantics.  Unfortunately, registers which can accept input from either above or below are apt to be expensive to realize, whether in VLSI or discrete logic.  RAM is a nice approach, but it's difficult to get underflow semantics which behave as described above.

A nice approach is to use a cross between the RAM and pushdown-stack approaches: each stack slot only loads from the one immediately above, but each stack slot has a flip flop which indicates whether it contains valid data.  Pushing an item in the stack causes each item to be loaded with the one above if all items above it are valid.  Popping an item in the stack causes the topmost valid item to be output and set to invalid.

If there are very many stack items, RAM will likely be cheaper than the pushdown stack described above, even if one needs to have both a stack pointer and a pushed-items counter (pushing when the stack is full should bump the stack pointer, but leave the pushed-items counter at maximum).  For two items, however, the push-down stack described above will be simpler (if one doesn't care about detecting stack underflow, one may omit the 'valid data' flip flop from the bottom slot).  For 2-8 items or so, either approach should be workable.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, this arrangement won't work.
It currently has both ALU inputs connected directly to the data bus without any intervening latch or register.
It currently has no way to present two different numbers to the input of the ALU, making it impossible to calculate "9 - 7".
Most stack machines I've seen have

- one ALU input hardwired to the output of TOP of stack,
- the other ALU input hardwired to NEXT of stack (or to the data bus connected to the memory where the rest of the stack is stored), and
- the ALU output hardwired to the input of TOP of stack.

*how can it count as a zero address machine that uses an address register?*

Normally I interpret "zero address" as meaning "[zero operand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_address_machine)" instruction set.
Since the sources and the destination of the "add" instruction are always top of stack, next on stack, and top of stack, they are implicit and don't need to be explicitly specified in each "add" instruction.
The "add" instruction on other CPUs explicitly points out 1, 2, or 3 operands (making them 1-operand, 2-operand, or 3-operand CPUs).
All the CPUs I've ever seen have more programmer-visible "address registers" than operands, and often have even more micro-architectural "address registers" invisible to the programmer.

See

- [the Canonical Stack Machine](http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/stack_computers/sec3_2.html#321)
- [Wikipedia: stack machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_machine)
- [Wikibook Microprocessor Design](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Microprocessor_Design/ALU)

Comment: How about wiring the second ALU to a register which is loaded from the stack?  Since a "pop" operation is going to be necessary, why not pop into that register, whereupon what used to be the "next" of stack would now be the top?

Comment: @supercat: Do you know of any hardware that works that way? It reminds me of the "A!" instruction of the F21 CPU. "Why not?" Does it have any advantage compared to the canonical stack machine? I don't think anyone knows yet.

Comment: Depending upon how a stack is implemented, I would expect that having a "next" output may not always the easiest thing in the world.  Using a pop to captures top-of-stack to an ALU-input dedicated register and then makes the previous "next" value be the top of stack would be a slight simplification, since the new register would only need one input (top-of-stack) and one output (the ALU).